# Dynamically change the log4net connection string

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I'm new to log4net and was given a task to Switch the way log4net gets the connectionstring.

The connectionstring may be different for different groups of people who visits the site. i.e.
company A has users who use the site and has its own db and therefore has its own logging table which log4net uses.

We were currently using a connection string in a webconfig file.

I created this code but doesn't work

```
MyNamspace
{
     public class Log4NetAdoNetAppender :log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
     {
          public new string ConnectionString
          {
                get { return base.ConnectionString; }
                set
                {                
                    base.ConnectionString = Service.GetConnectionString();
                }
          }
     }
}

<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="MyNamspace.Log4NetAdoNetAppender">
```

Comment: and what happens exactly in your does not work? can you debug and check which connection string is used at runtime?

Comment: then can you try to specify the assembly name before the MyNamespace word in the type definition?

Comment: You are defining a  **new** ConnectionString property, but how are you actually using or calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could:

- Configure log4net by code instead of by xml
- configure as many loggers and appenders as "connection strings"
- use the right logger to log based on the user

Hope it helps

Comment: You can also put the "current" logger in the call context, a thread static field or in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection and access it from a static way from any place of your app.